# PHP - Running multiple foreach loops causes page to stop loading data

Tags: php

I am creating a personal project which is a time punch application. On this page *(refer to [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIyxa.png))*, I am using foreach loop(s) to call in a list of pay periods *(both past & present)* and employee punch data. I am also using a foreach loop to check the status of the employee if they have punched IN, OUT for break, IN from break, OUT for lunch, IN from lunch, or OUT for the day.

Previously, I had this page dedicated only to seeing the "In Day" button and a live clock. But, after realizing how much dead space I have on this page, I decided I wanted to display the employee timesheet `<table>` as well. However, after reloading the page, the live clock disappears and the employee punch data doesn't load, along with the list of pay-periods under the `<select>` element.

Once the error occurred, I tried to think what causes the page to stop. So, I tried to comment out the foreach loop that calls in a list of the pay periods & *voila*, the employee punch data for the timesheet *displays*. But now, that leaves the list of pay periods under the `<select>` element, empty, with no data. I tried commenting out the foreach loops that load in the employee punch data and yes, the list of pay periods displays. I also tried commenting out the loop that checks the status of the employee, and now both the list of pay periods and employee punch data display.

The context for using a foreach loop to check the status of the employee: I use it to *determine* the allowed punches (IN/OUT buttons) the employee can make.

I didn't want to assume that having multiple foreach loops in a page would cause the app to break like this, but I guess since I came across this problem, *what* would you suggest as a fix that would solve an issue like this? *Would* you say there is a better way to get all of this data without having multiple foreach loops.

**Foreach Loop that determines allowed punches the employee can make**

```
function buttonGroup($params)
{

    $params = filterParams($params);
    $params = getEmpStatus($params);

    foreach ($params['results'] as $row)
    {

        switch ($row['emp_status'])
        {

            case 'OUT':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="in_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Day</button>';
            break;

            case 'IN':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="out_break_1" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-yellow-500 text-white">Out Break</button>';
            break;

            case 'OUT_BREAK_1':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="in_break_1" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Break</button>';
            break;
            
            case 'IN_BREAK_1':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="out_lunch" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-blue-700 text-white">Out Lunch</button>';
            break;

            case 'OUT_LUNCH':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="in_lunch" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Lunch</button>';
            break;

            case 'IN_LUNCH':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="out_break_2" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-yellow-500 text-white">Out Break</button>';
            break;

            case 'OUT_BREAK_2':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="in_break_2" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Break</button>';
            break;

            case 'IN_BREAK_2':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>';
            break;

        }

    }

    return $params;

}
```

**Foreach Loop that pulls in list of pay periods**

```
function viewPayPeriods($params)
{

    $params = filterParams($params);
    $params['results'] = getPayPeriods($params);

    foreach ($params['results'] as $row)
    {

        $params['payPeriodsList'] =
        '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['pp_start'])).''.' - '.''.date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['pp_end'])).'</option>';

        echo $params['payPeriodsList'];

    }

}
```

**Foreach Loop that pulls in employee punch data**

```
function readOnlyTimesheet($params)
{

    $params = filterParams($params);
    $params['results'] = userPunchData($params);

    foreach ($params['results'] as $row)
    {

        $params['timesheetRow'] =
        '<tr>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900 text-center">'.date('D m/d/Y', strtotime($row['punch_day'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_day'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_break_1'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_break_1'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_lunch'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_lunch'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_break_2'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_break_2'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_day'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.$row['total_hours'].'</td>
        </tr>';

        echo $params['timesheetRow'];

    }

}
```

**Home Page that loads in data as described above**

```
    <section class="px-4 py-6">
    <div class="container mx-auto space-y-4">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-1">
            <div id="time" class="font-semibold text-3xl"></div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-4">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <?php 
                
                $params = buttonGroup($params);

                echo $params['buttonGroup'];
                
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="px-4 py-6">
    <div class="container mx-auto w-2/3 space-y-4">
        <form action="" method="post" class="w-1/3 flex flex-row items-end space-x-4">
            <div>
                <label for="HeadlineAct" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                    Select Pay-Period:
                </label>
                <select name="pay_period" id="HeadlineAct" class="mt-1.5 p-2 w-full rounded-lg border-gray-300 text-gray-700 sm:text-sm">
                    <?php

                    $params = viewPayPeriods($params);

                    echo $params['payPeriodsList'];

                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="pp_view" class="rounded-lg bg-blue-600 px-5 py-2 font-medium text-white">View</button>
        </form>
        <div class="rounded-lg border border-gray-200 overflow-hidden">
            <table class="w-full divide-y-2 divide-gray-200 bg-white text-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            Date
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            In Day
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            Out Break
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            In Break
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            Out Lunch
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            In Lunch
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            Out Break
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            In Break
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            Out Day
                        </th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
                            Total Hours
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <?php

                    $params = readOnlyTimesheet($params);

                    echo $params['timesheetRow'];

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-end">
            <span class="font-medium">Total Hours worked: <?php $params = viewTotalHours($params); echo $params['totalHours']; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's not only to have multiple loops stacked in each other (those do work, but you need to concentrate and keep track), it is often also to have many lines within the foreach body. For the code you present I would extract the HTML output into a template layer and pass view variables to it from the transaction script.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't enabled ERRORS to show in PHP. `readOnlyTimesheet` has echo inside of it and doesn't return anything.  And you are overriding $params with the return of `readOnlyTimesheet` which it doesn't do. Then you `echo $params['timesheetRow'];` but that doesn't exist in $params

Comment: @imvain2: it's easy to miss, I also wondered: it gets set in the code before the echo, it's just a multiline string so not obvious (and superfluous). good tip for errors, I was close to share to plaster this creative code with assert() calls, but I fear the concept is hard to understand/apply.

Comment: The first place to look for clues when data you expect is not arriving at your browser is in your logs

Comment: Thank you @imvain2 & hakre for your comments! I answered my question and credited you guys in the post!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to hakre & imvain2 for your comments on my question and giving some pointers. I was able to solve it by reading imvain2's answer.

What I did to fix the issue:

- Since I have echo's in my functions(), I decided to test and comment out the echo's that I am running in my index.php

```html
<section class="px-4 py-6">
  <div class="container mx-auto space-y-4">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-1">
      <div id="time" class="font-semibold text-3xl"></div>
      <div id="date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-4">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <?php 
                    
                    $params = buttonGroup($params);

                    // echo $params['buttonGroup'];
                    
                    ?>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="px-4 py-6">
  <div class="container mx-auto w-2/3 space-y-4">
    <form action="" method="post" class="w-1/3 flex flex-row items-end space-x-4">
      <div>
        <label for="HeadlineAct" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                        Select Pay-Period:
                    </label>
        <select name="pay_period" id="HeadlineAct" class="mt-1.5 p-2 w-full rounded-lg border-gray-300 text-gray-700 sm:text-sm">
          <?php

                        $params = viewPayPeriods($params);

                        // echo $params['payPeriodsList'];

                        ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="pp_view" class="rounded-lg bg-blue-600 px-5 py-2 font-medium text-white">View</button>
    </form>
    <div class="rounded-lg border border-gray-200 overflow-hidden">
      <table class="w-full divide-y-2 divide-gray-200 bg-white text-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              Date
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              In Day
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              Out Break
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              In Break
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              Out Lunch
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              In Lunch
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              Out Break
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              In Break
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              Out Day
            </th>
            <th class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900">
              Total Hours
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
          <?php

                        $params = readOnlyTimesheet($params);

                        // echo $params['timesheetRow'];

                        ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-end">
      <span class="font-medium">Total Hours worked: <?php $params = viewTotalHours($params); echo $params['totalHours']; ?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And imvain2 mentions that while having echo's in my function (readOnlyTimesheet), I have `return $params`; and points out that I am not returning anything. I appreciate you for pointing that out. So after trying a couple things out, like commenting out my echo's in my `index.php` & just utilizing what I have in my functions() and getting rid of my `return $params`, I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxPtq.png).

```html
function buttonGroup($params)
{

    $params = filterParams($params);
    $params = getEmpStatus($params);

    foreach ($params['results'] as $row)
    {

        switch ($row['emp_status'])
        {

            case 'OUT':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="in_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Day</button>';
            break;

            case 'IN':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="out_break_1" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-yellow-500 text-white">Out Break</button>';
            break;

            case 'OUT_BREAK_1':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="in_break_1" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Break</button>';
            break;
            
            case 'IN_BREAK_1':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="out_lunch" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-blue-700 text-white">Out Lunch</button>';
            break;

            case 'OUT_LUNCH':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="in_lunch" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Lunch</button>';
            break;

            case 'IN_LUNCH':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="out_break_2" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-yellow-500 text-white">Out Break</button>';
            break;

            case 'OUT_BREAK_2':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>
                <button type="submit" name="in_break_2" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Break</button>';
            break;

            case 'IN_BREAK_2':
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                '<button type="submit" name="out_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-red-700 text-white">Out Day</button>';
            break;

            default:
                $params['buttonGroup'] = 
                    '<button type="submit" name="in_day" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-green-500 text-white">In Day</button>';
            break;

        }

        echo $params['buttonGroup'];

    }

    // return $params;

}

function readOnlyTimesheet($params)
{

    $params = filterParams($params);
    $params['results'] = userPunchData($params);

    foreach ($params['results'] as $row)
    {

        $params['timesheetRow'] =
        '<tr>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 font-medium text-gray-900 text-center">'.date('D m/d/Y', strtotime($row['punch_day'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_day'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_break_1'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_break_1'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_lunch'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_lunch'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_break_2'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['in_break_2'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.date('H:i:s A', strtotime($row['out_day'])).'</td>
            <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-4 py-2 text-gray-700 text-center">'.$row['total_hours'].'</td>
        </tr>';

        echo $params['timesheetRow'];

    }

    // return $params;

}

function viewPayPeriods($params)
{

    $params = filterParams($params);
    $params['results'] = getPayPeriods($params);

    foreach ($params['results'] as $row)
    {

        $params['payPeriodsList'] =
        '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['pp_start'])).''.' - '.''.date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['pp_end'])).'</option>';

        echo $params['payPeriodsList'];

    }

    // return $params;

}
```

Thank you once again hakre & imvain2! I appreciate you taking the time reading my question and pointing out some errors within my code. It's always refreshing seeing people in the community help each other out.